# How can I view my profile on a child meta site in the Android or iOS app?

Tags: support, profile-page, android-app, ios-app, per-site-meta

How can I view my profile on a child meta (Meta Stack Overflow, Meta Super User, etc.) in the Stack Exchange Android or iOS apps? Can't find link to it.

Comment: Looks like the apps (iOS app for me, same behavior) show the parent site profile only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you visit your profile by clicking on your name from the left pull out, tap the "All X sites" button under the three top main sites displayed. Inside that screen, next to the search box at the top change the "Main sites" dropdown to "Meta sites" or "All sites" to view child meta profiles.